# unix socket file on disk vs tmpfs on ubuntu

Tags: linux, optimization, ramdisk, unix-socket

Is there a difference in speed (regardless of how infinitesimal) if you place a unix socket file on disk rather than tmpfs/ramdisk (ubuntu)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only at open time. The file never actually gains any contents; what is sent over it passes through memory only. The file system is only used to provide a system-wide name.

Comment: so given that, is it better to use tmpfs?